# Why can I call a PHP function in a class statically without the method having been declared the static keyword?

Tags: php, static

This code is from [osTicket](http://osticket.com/), https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/blob/1.9.x/main.inc.php,

```
   /**** static functions ****/
    function start() {
        // Prep basic translation support
        Internationalization::bootstrap();

        if(!($ost = new osTicket()))
            return null;

        //Set default time zone... user/staff settting will override it (on login).
        $_SESSION['TZ_OFFSET'] = $ost->getConfig()->getTZoffset();
        $_SESSION['TZ_DST'] = $ost->getConfig()->observeDaylightSaving();

        // Bootstrap installed plugins
        $ost->plugins->bootstrap();

        // Mirror content updates to the search backend
        $ost->searcher = new SearchInterface();

        return $ost;
    }
```

In another [file](https://github.com/osTicket/osTicket/blob/1.9.x/bootstrap.php), this is done:

```
osTicket::start()
```

It works.  How come the static keyword isn't required?

EDIT:  Does this work in other languages?

Comment: you can call any object method/function statically, but if that function uses `$this`, then you'll get warnings about using `$this` in a static/non-object context.

Comment: Is that just in PHP?

Comment: well, it's ok in php. no idea about "all" other languages.

Comment: Depends on the version of PHP: You'll get a deprecated message in PHP7, meaning that the "issue" will be "fixed" (and the static keyword made mandatory for any method that is called statically) in a future version, while 5.5/5.6 will give you a straightforward warnig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historic reasons. PHP 4 didn't have the `static` keyword and many code bases used members statically. Fixing such old code base is hard and enforcing this would have prevented adoption.

Comment: Yes, back in the days you could call all method statically and dynamically. such stuff was possible: `class C { function m() { echo isset($this) ? 'dynamic' : 'static'; } } C::m(); $c = new C; $c->m();` and people did ..